# How to create agenda mode that will list all entries with time against them that have no tag?

Tags: org-mode

As the title, trying to make an agenda item that will list all entries that have at least one minute clocked against them, but no tag.

I can get it to list entries with no tag easy, but I can't get it to list items with time clocked against them.

Looking at special properties on [this page](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties), it seems like `CLOCKSUM` should be exactly what I am looking for.

This is what I've got, but I can't make it work:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  (quote
    (("t" "All items with time logged, but no tag" tags "+CLOCKSUM>=\"0:01\"" nil))))
```

The page says to run `org-clock-sum` first, but this doesn't seem to have helped. I tried [org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda), but that wouldn't do it either.

I've been bashing my head against this for hours, couldn't find anything on the internet. Can anyone help?

Using Emacs 26.3 and Orgmode 9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your conditions to the `org-agenda-skip-function` variable.

> Documentation: Function to be called at each match during agenda
>   construction. If this function returns nil, the current match should
>   not be skipped. Otherwise, the function must return a position from
>   where the search should be continued.

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("t" "All items with time logged, but no tag"
         ((alltodo "" ((org-agenda-skip-function
                        (lambda ()
                          (if (and (null (org-get-tags))
                                   (>= (org-clock-sum-current-item) 1))
                              nil
                            (or (outline-next-heading)
                                (point-max)))))))))))
```

Comment: That never would have occured to me, but it worked beautifully. I have spent 6 hours on this, you are an absolute star.